# Displaying only one component of the list

Tags: list-manipulation

I wrote a code which gives me a list which has one coordinate point (for example {{10,11}})

I was wondering how i can only take the y part (which is 11)

I tried using:

```
data2 = b[[1 ;; 0]]
```

but that eliminates both parts

Answer (score 3):

The double semicolon syntax `list[[i ;; j]]` gives you a span of elements, not different levels. So, with `l = {a,b,c}`, `l[[2 ;; 3]]` gives `{b,c}`. You'll want to use commas instead! Note also that Mathematica lists start at `1`, not `0`.

So you'll want `b[[1, 2]]`. This is equivalent to `b[[1]][[2]]`, giving the first part of `{{10,11}}`, which is `{10,11}`, and then the second part of that, which is `11`.